# Use of ところ in this sentence

Tags: grammar, aspect

> 永沢君たちって、...なんていうかジメジメしてる**ところ**が怒られるもとになってるでしょ？
>   As for Nakasawa's crew,...how do I put it? Their gloominess becomes the source of them getting told off. Right? (my best-guess translation)

I thought してるところ was "in the middle of doing", but I can't get the sentence to work with that translation. "The source of being told off is 'in the middle of'/while/during being gloomy"? The implication seems to be that they only get told off when they are gloomy.

Have I totally messed up the overall translation? Could you please clarify how ところ is working here? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

してるところ would mean "in the middle of doing" if the term before that was a verb. E.g. I'm in the middle of driving right now (今運転してるところ).

However, it can also mean "that part". E.g. The gloomy part of you. So in this case, your "best-guess translation" is correct!

Comment: But 「ジメジメしてる」 is certainly a verb phrase, too.  You might want to explain the decisive difference between 「ジメジメしてる」 and 「運転してる」.